Is it allowed to use thread and undefined sanitizers at the same time?
I'm using the -fsanitize=thread,undefined option in my project. When running the thread, the sanitizer indicates a race.
// Compiled on g++ 11.4 with the command g++ ./main.cc -fsanitize=undefined,thread
#include <thread>
int main()
{
    std::thread t1([]{});
    std::thread t2([]{});
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

In this example, the thread sanitizer sees a race:
  Write of size 8 at 0x7b0400000800 by thread T2:
    #0 pipe <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x3fba8)
    #1 __sanitizer::IsAccessibleMemoryRange(unsigned long, unsigned long) <null> (libubsan.so.1+0x1f3e3)
    #2 std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<main::{lambda()#2}> > >::~_State_impl() <null> (a.out+0x402111)
    #3 execute_native_thread_routine <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdbadd)

  Previous write of size 8 at 0x7b0400000800 by thread T1:
    #0 pipe <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x3fba8)
    #1 __sanitizer::IsAccessibleMemoryRange(unsigned long, unsigned long) <null> (libubsan.so.1+0x1f3e3)
    #2 std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<main::{lambda()#1}> > >::~_State_impl() <null> (a.out+0x4022e9)
    #3 execute_native_thread_routine <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0xdbadd)

Here is a compilation on a different version of g++ and the latest version of clang. There, the sanitizer also detects a race.

I'm generally "disillusioned" about the sanitizer...cr*p. I tried adding it to my projects debug build, got lots of false positives, some even "pre-announced" by sanitizer telling me its not supporting something and there will be false positives following. That's just useless; I'm not going to waste my time trying to dig through false positives every time I run the software for the odd chance that there might be an actual problem somewhere in that pile; I'll just stick with the good old "if there is an actual bug, it will lead to a crash eventually".

I'm generally "disillusioned" about the sanitizer...cr*p. - yes tool has some limitations and may trigger false positive, but when configured properly is a great guard from many subtle mistakes. It is far from perfect, but helps makes code a lot safer. Calling it a "cr*p" is big big overstatement.

The sanitizers that cannot be used together are: address, memory, thread.  The thread and undefined can be used together.  Note that thread is in beta stage.
